# calculating estimated GAME Credits per day?

Tags: mining-profitability

So i am trying to work out my estimated game credits per day.

I have the follwoing info

- Difficulty 12982 (at time of testing)
- Hash Rate 600MH
- Block Reward 12.5 (i believe)

I have tried to calculate with the following:

$blockreward /($difficulty*2^32/$hashrate/3600/24);

The result is: 0.00048143583423201 which i know isnt right. Can somoneone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Most people would look for an existing profitability calculator or two. Is that the same as this? https://www.coinwarz.com/calculators/gamecredits-mining-calculator

Comment: I am currently making an application, so would need to code my own.

Comment: So, look at the java script of an existing one.